# Upgrading Stack in NixOS to Bleeding Edge Git Build

Tags: haskell-stack, nix, nixos

I run NixOS, and so am having trouble updating `stack` as `nixpkgs` always lags behind on my stable branch. From [the official docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#nixos) we can build the following function to upgrade `stack`:

```
upgradeLocalStackInNixOS() {
  git clone https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack.git stack
  cd stack
  cabal2nix --shell ./. --no-check --no-haddock > shell.nix
  nix-env -i -f shell.nix
}
```

**Problem:** This generates the following error:

```
Cloning into 'stack'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 44411, done.
remote: Total 44411 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 44411
Receiving objects: 100% (44411/44411), 14.82 MiB | 1.05 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (31314/31314), done.
*** found package.yaml. Using hpack...
error: 'f' at /home/george/.dotfiles/nixos/stack/shell.nix:7:7 called without required argument 'pantry', at /nix/store/i9f158cv3dfkn30pb4bssba575h7f409-nixos-18.09.1446.db561c90ef3/nixos/pkgs/development/haskel
l-modules/make-package-set.nix:87:27
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need a git version, consider the last options at the end below the horizontal line.

These are some methods:

## cabal2nix

`pantry` is a package that is distributed with stack. You could probably run cabal2nix in its directory and wire up the Nix expressions by hand.

## stack

A straightforward solution may be to `stack build stack` using your previous `stack`. Although straightforward, it is not a good solution because it does not create garbage collection roots for the dependencies of your `stack` executable.

## stack2nix

This is a bit more experimental, a bit more automatic, yet still requires a little bit of intervention.

```
stack2nix --test --platform x86_64-linux --hackage-snapshot 2018-12-16T10:00:00Z . > stack-custom-snapshot.nix
```

You now have a generated package set similar to `pkgs.haskell.packages.*` including the packages in `stack.yaml`. You will have to disable tests for stack and pantry. This can be done via an overlay (another topic) or by adding `doCheck = false;` to both packages' arguments in `stack-custom-snapshot.nix`. It also needs a little help to find `libyaml`:

```
nix-env -i -f stack-custom-snapshot.nix -A stack --arg pkgs 'import <nixpkgs> { overlays = [(self: super: { yaml = super.libyaml; })]; }'
```

## overlay

You may be able to override the source attribute of the stack package using an overlay. This requires some experience with overlays and only works well if the dependency requirements of stack haven't changed between the packaged Stack and the git version.

---

## Nixpkgs unstable

Although not precisely the answer to your original question, is easier and sufficient solution for getting *a* recent version of stack. I'll discuss options to install from git below.

You can include packages from any Nixpkgs version in your NixOS configuration or user profile.

### By channel

First add the channel

```
nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable nixos-unstable
nix-channel --update     # actually fetch your channels
```

In your NixOS configuration

```
environment.systemPackages =
  let
    unstable = import <nixos-unstable> {};
  in
    [ pkgs.figlet unstable.stack pkgs.hello ];
```

### nix-env

For `nix-env` create a file `stack-from-unstable.nix`

```
(import <nixos-unstable> {}).stack
```

and then

```
nix-env -i -f `stack-from-unstable.nix`
```

### Pinned nixpkgs

Instead of `import <nixos-unstable>` you can use one of the [pinning techniques](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/FAQ/Pinning_Nixpkgs). This will ensure that subsequent attempts to install it produce the same outcome. This means you'll have to update it manually.